# How to enable SSH X11 forwarding through additional server?

Tags: linux, ssh, x11

I have hosts A,B and C. From host A I can access through ssh only B. From B I can access C. 
I want to be able to run X11 programs on C and forward display to A.

I tried this:

```
A$ ssh -X B
B$ ssh -X C
C$ xclock
Error: Can't open display:
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, the one I prefer is to forward the ssh port:

First, connect to machine B and forward [localPort] to C:22 through B

```
A$ ssh -L [localPort]:C:22 B
```

Next, connect to C from A through this newly-created tunnel using [localPort], forwarding X11

```
A$ ssh -X -p [localPort] localhost
```

Now we can run X11 programs on C and have them display on A

```
C$ xclock
```

[localPort] can be any port that you are not already listening to on A, I often use 2222 for simplicity.

Comment: not exactly... if X11Forwarding is not enabled on server C, it won't work. it also won't work unless one sets AllowTcpForwarding yes and GatewayPorts yes on server B. this answer is not acceptable at all

Comment: You make a good point, I did not notice this since I use debian, on which X11Forwarding and AllowTcpForwarding are enabled by default.

GatewayPorts is not needed since when it is disabled, SSH still listens on localhost and that is what we are connecting to. You would only need it if you wanted to make the second connection via an external IP for machine A.

Comment: On step 1, it didn't ask me the password for host B, and I end up connected in host C. In another window I tried step 2 and I get "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host".

Comment: ssh: connect to host ... port 22: Connection refused while executing the first command

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried with

```
A$ ssh -Y B
B$ ssh -Y C
C$ xlclock
```

The -Y flag "Enables trusted X11 forwarding."

Comment: The same result.

Comment: This worked for me, but only to discover how slow is X11

Comment: add also -C (compression). much faster

Answer (score 8):

This can easily be accomplished using port forwarding:

```
A$ ssh -NL 2022:C:22 B &
A$ ssh -X -p 2022 localhost
C$ xclock
```

Port localhost:2022 is forwarded to C:22 via B
SSH to C via localhost:2022
Use X as normal

Comment: This won't work for the same reasons noted elsewhere in case B (the gateway) does not have the correct sshd forwarding options enabled.

Comment: didn't ask for my password to host B, which is weird; and it didn't work, I got the error message "channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host"

Answer (score 5):

For newer versions opensshd you have to disable `X11UseLocalhost` for this to work.

You need to do this on Host C's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart sshd for this to work:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost no
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the problem is that the middle machine doesn't have X, but it otherwise configured to allow forwarding X11, just install xauth.

on a yum-based system (fedora, redhat, centos):

```
B$ sudo yum install xauth
```

on an apt-based system (debian, ubuntu):

```
B$ sudo apt-get install xauth
```

Comment: Yay- perfect for headless raspberry pi.

Comment: @cmc or using ssh like a vpn.

Comment: @cmc do you have `yum` on a pi?

Comment: nope- sudo apt-get install xauth

Answer (score 3):

If you often go from A to C, you can configure B as a proxy:

`A:~/.ssh/config`:

> ```
> Host C
>   ForwardX11   yes
>   ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p B
> ```

then it's just:

```
A$ ssh C xclock
```

Answer (score 2):

You could combine -Y/-X command with the -J command line option:

```
A$ ssh -Y user@C -J user@B
C$ xclock
```

If you have more Hosts to hop than just do the following:

```
A$ ssh -Y user@C -J user@B,user@D,...,user@Z
C$ xclock
```

From man ssh:

```
-J [user@]host[:port]
     Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to
     the jump host and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the
     ultimate destination from there.  Multiple jump hops may be
     specified separated by comma characters.  This is a shortcut to
     specify a ProxyJump configuration directive.
```

It was introduced in OpenSSH version 7.3 (released in August 2016).

Answer (score 1):

You can't forward X11 display if you have X11Forwarding disabled in any sshd you are using.

man sshd_config:

```
X11Forwarding
  Specifies whether X11 forwarding is permitted. The argument must be “yes”
  or “no”.  The default is “no”.
```

You have to make sure X11Forwarding is enabled on destination *and* all intermediate sshds you are using.

Just a small hint: you should try to use VNC, X11 display forwarding is quite bandwidth consuming.

Comment: @AgentK's and @dave's suggestions only require X11Forwarding to be enabled on the final host, as they use an SSH tunnel to bypass the intermediate host. Your suggestion is almost definitely why the OP's method failed at first, but that doesn't mean other people's answers "are not acceptable"

Comment: their answers were defective and remedied the problem, not solving it. a right and useful answer would consider the original question and solving it, and providing other ways _only in case_ the originals question is not solvable. by the way, neither of them  mentioned X11Forwarding, which is essential

Comment: On some systems the default is "`yes`".

Comment: I checked, that X11Forwarding is enabled on B and C and AllowTcpForwarding is set to yes on B. But the result of my commands is the same. And dave's answer works fine for me.

Comment: then do that, but it's only a remedy. you also can start ssh with parameter '-v', or try echo $DISPLAY all the nested ssh commands to find it out where $DISPLAY get lost