# Forwarding X11 with one hop without X-server installed

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, x11forwarding, xserver

## problem

I want to run X-applications remotely on a machine C from my client A. The only way to connect to this machine is by using machine B (firewall) as a hop:

A --> B --> C

So far, simple ssh works as expected, however I can't get X11 forwarding running.

I have found some similar questions, but I think they all assume that X11 is running on B. Solutions like [How to enable SSH X11 forwarding through additional server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/53080/how-to-enable-ssh-x11-forwarding-through-additional-server) seem not to be working with my setup.

Could it be that you need to have a X-server running on B to forward X11 from C to B and B to A?

## setup

I have set up my ~./ssh/ssh_config on A according to this article: http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html

When I try to connect and forward X11 from C by using

```
$A: ssh -X C
```

I get connected to C through B, but without X11 forwarding (although enabled on B and C):

```
$C: echo $DISPLAY

$C: glxgears 
Error: couldn't open display (null)
```

## machines used

- A: Arch Linux 3.13.7-1-ARCH notebook running X-server/gnome
- B: Debian 6 Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 pc no X-server installed/running
- C: OpenSuse 13.1 3.11.10-7-desktop pc running X-server/gnome

## conclusion

I'm not sure if the problem exists because of my configuration/setup or this would not word in general...
I would appreciate if anyone with similar problem/experience could help me out!

Comment: You need `xauth` but not the X server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the X11 forwarding will work in the described multi-hop scenario.

However, if you were to first establish an ssh connection A->B with port forwarding to C:22 and then connect to C with X11 forwarding through the established 'direct' connection that should work just fine.

Something like the following:

`A $ ssh -L2200:C:22 -N B` (possibly putting that to the background)

followed by:

`A $ ssh -X -p2200 localhost`

Comment: Thanks! This works after I added `X11UseLocalhost no` in `sshd_config` on C.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a ProxyCommand, then don't use -X for the ProxyCommand. The ProxyCommand should leave all the advanced features disabled, you only need the bare minimum for the ProxyCommand.

When using a ProxyCommand to ssh from A to B and connect to port 22 on C using nc, the ssh client on A will be communicating with the ssh server on C. The implication of this is that nothing that happens on B can affect which features you can make use of between A and C. It would be impossible for B to have any influence, since the communication is encrypted as it passes through B.

The explanation for why X11 forwarding is not working for you has to be found on either A or C. The command you typed on A looks correct to me, so there are two explanations left, which I can think of:

1. You did not have a DISPLAY variable in the shell, where you typed the ssh command.
2. The ssh server on C is configured to disallow X11 forwarding. You need "X11Forwarding yes" in sshd_config on C, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! The problem was the missing `X11UseLocalhost no` in `sshd_config`on C. With that added and `-X` removed from ProxyCommand everything works as expected

Answer (score 0):

In a multihop setup line that with X11 forwarding you need xauth on every machine. That is the only X11 application you need on machine B. Machine A is the only machine that needs an X server. Machine C of course needs your X11 applications, but does not need a X server. In theory you could even do this with no X11 applications on Machine A.